# Replace some files using EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I use [EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/) in eclipse.I created a repository for a project and there,I had a class for example `ClassA` in `com.first.pack` that was added to index.Then,for some reasons I created another project (that is not under GIT) and copied `ClassA` in `com.second.pack` of second project and complete it's task.

Now I'm looking for a way to replace `ClassA` in `com.first.pack` with same class in `com.second.pack` without losing it's history.
I know I can copy content of second class and paste in first one,but really there are some other classes with some situation and it is not a clean way to do for all of them! Also I know there is a [replace](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Replace) command in GIT,but I'm not acquaintance with `command line` and I do not know how I can do it in EGit.

So how I can do that in EGit ?

Comment: The best solution is simply to overwrite the files as you have suggested, either by pasting their contents and saving, or simply by copying them using  your preferred file manager. Then commit the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need it's history ?

You can commit and push your actual situation, then replace `com.first.package.ClassA` with the ClassA from `com.second.package`.
GIT will looks like it : you delete the file ClassA, then create a new file called ClasseA
After that commit again and push.

Git will allow you to get history through your dual commit.

In the History View, you will be able to point at a commit ID, then browse through files (created, delete or edited) in the state while performing the commit

At some point, you should be able to get used the commandline, because it allows you to fully use git, and understand what you do.